# rails 4, activeAdmin, Devise not saving reset_password_token for admin_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I am using [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) to create other admin members by supplying email, and having a block to send a password reset to the newly added email:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  def password_required?
    new_record? ? false : super
  end
end
```

However, I started getting a `reset token invalid` error, and on checking, discovered that the `reset_password_token` is not getting saved.

When I tried to debug, I traced the error to the method of the set_reset_password_token method of the `Recoverable` module ( `recoverable.rb` file ) of devise:

```
def set_reset_password_token
  raw, enc = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)

  self.reset_password_token   = enc
  self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
  self.save(validate: false)
  raw
end
```

the token is getting generated, but when I checked `self` just before the `self.save(validate: false)` line, there was nothing attached to `self.reset_password_token`, it was nil.

To finally complicate it for me, when i now manually run the line `self.reset_password_token   = enc` and `self.reset_password_token` actually now holds the token, after saving it, and checking the database, the `reset_password_token` of the newly saved AdminUser was still nil.

What could be going on here?

> Note however: [devise test suit on git](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/test/models/recoverable_test.rb) shows that this should not be the case as shown below:

```
test 'should not clear reset password token for new user' do
  user = new_user
  assert_nil user.reset_password_token

  user.send_reset_password_instructions
  assert_present user.reset_password_token

  user.save
  assert_present user.reset_password_token
end
```

Comment: Hi! How did this ever work out like for you? Did you get a solution?
I'm running into the same problem right now! If I find what to do I'll post an answer.

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos I later decided to go with another Ruby Gem to handle the reset password. the gem is: [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable)